# How to redirect with nginx but keep the old url

Tags: nginx, redirect, subdomain

I have mainsite.com and a subdomain sub.mainsite.com.

The sub.mainsite.com has a cname record point to another online content web

Right now I will to redirect mainsite.com/sub to display the sub.mainsite.com content, but still keep the mainsite.com/sub URL.

How can I do that with Nginx?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that. You can either redirect using `return` or `rewrite` directive. Either way, the URL is redirected. The difference is you can reframe the URL as required using `rewrite` directive.